# How to change the color of braces in JSX & TSX in Intellij 2022.3

Tags: intellij-idea, colors, jsx, settings, braces

I just updated to version 2022.3 of Intellij Ultimate, and the color for braces in jsx/tsx code blocks has turned to yellow, but I want to revert it to the original color.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OW1XQ.png)In this image, the curly braces around the values for the props are yellow but they should be the same color as the text for the prop names "isOpen" & "toggle"

I looked through the color settings for relevant languages but could not find anything that sounded like it would be the correct setting to change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try editing **Settings | Editor | Color Scheme | XML, Tag** foreground color

Comment: This changed the braces indeed, but it also changed the angle brackets < and >, which I don't want. Any way I can configure the color settings to not have these tied to the same color?

Comment: there are no settings for this

Comment: FYI Previous color is #E8BF6A